# Supported data types in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink

I am confused by the official documentation of Apache Flink.

In the section [Planner Compatiblity](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/types.html#new-blink-planner) **is mentioned**, that **CHAR** and **VARCHAR** are **not supported** by using Blink Planner.

But CHAR and VARCHAR are in the [list of data types](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/types.html#list-of-data-types) at the end of the site.

So my question is, if there are some types missing in the Blink table or is it realy not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHAR and VARCHAR are supported. The documentation is not correct there.